# Vb.net how to display the frequency of digits from a text file

Tags: vb.net, text-files, frequency

I am still studying this stuff and been looking through google and Youtube but there doesn't seem to have this problem for VB.net I saw some on python or Java though. This is the output that I have to get but when i read the text file and try to find the frequency its doesn't go as hoped

[image]

This is my code.

[image]

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

        Dim reader As TextReader = New StreamReader("number.txt")
        Dim num As Integer = 0

        For Each item In reader.ReadToEnd
            If item.CompareTo(reader.ReadLine) = True Then
                num += 1
            End If

        Next

        rtbshow.Text = "Digit" & " " & " " & " Frequency " & vbNewLine & reader.ReadToEnd() & " " & " " & num

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: And can you [edit] your question to give us a *small* sample of the file it is reading, please?

Comment: I just read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example but I don't think I have enough understanding on this thing to reproduce a similar thing unless its literally just creating a different text file and button name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary can work for this, but given just the nine digits an indexed array can do just as well and probably be faster.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    Dim digitCounts = Enumerable.Repeat(0,10).ToArray()

    Dim digits = File.ReadAllText("number.txt").
                   Where(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)).
                   Select(Function(c) Asc(c) - Asc("0"c))
    For Each d As Integer In digits
        digitCounts(d) += 1
    Next
    Dim result As New StringBuilder($"Digit{vbTab}Frequency{vbCrLf}")
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        result.AppendLine($"{i,3}{vbTab}{digitCounts(i),7}")
    Next
    rtbshow.Text = result.ToString()
End Sub
```

You can (kind of) see it working here, except I couldn't get .Net fiddle to do the string interpolation:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/FMWnMg

We could also solve this with a [`GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__) operation:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    Dim result As New StringBuilder($"Digit{vbTab}Frequency{vbCrLf}")
    Dim digits = File.ReadAllText("number.txt").
             Where(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)).
             OrderBy(Function(d) d).
             GroupBy(Function(d) d, 
                     Function(d, g) $"{d,3}{vbTab}{g.Count(),7}{vbCrLf}"
             )
    
    For Each d As String in digits
        result.Append(d)
    Next
    rtbshow.Text = result.ToString()
End Sub
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xxl2z3

Note this last skips missing digits.

Comment: Thanks a lot but could you help explain what you used, most of the stuff is so foreign to me that even when I google them I still don't have much grasp on it like where did this (Function(c) come from and this part 

Dim result As New StringBuilder($"Digit{vbTab}Frequency{vbCrLf}")
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        result.AppendLine($"{i,3}{vbTab}{digitCounts(i),7}")

Comment: One more LINQ function, Aggregate, and this is all done in one LINQ chain: `rtbshow.Text = File.ReadAllText("number.txt").Where(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)).GroupBy(Function(c) c).Select(Function(g) New KeyValuePair(Of Char, Integer)(g.Key, g.Count())).OrderBy(Function(g) g.Key).Aggregate($"Digit   Frequency", Function(acc, kvp) $"{acc}{Environment.NewLine}  {kvp.Key}  {kvp.Value}")`

Answer (score 2):

A [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) provides a convenient entity to store the (digit, count_of_digit) data.

Then you just need to go through all the characters in the file and check if each one is a digit. If it is, then add one to the count_of_digit for that digit.

This is an example using a Console Application:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub CreateTestFile(s As String)
        Dim rand As New Random()

        Using sw As New StreamWriter(s)
            For i = 1 To 10000
                sw.Write(rand.Next(0, 10).ToString())
            Next
        End Using

    End Sub

    Function GetNumberFrequencies(s As String) As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
        Dim nf As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
        For i = 0 To 9
            nf.Add(i, 0)
        Next

        Using sr As New StreamReader(s)
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                Dim line = sr.ReadLine()
                For Each c In line
                    If c >= "0" AndAlso c <= "9" Then
                        ' A quick way to convert the strings "0"-"9" to the numbers 0-9:
                        Dim index = AscW(c) - AscW("0)")
                        nf(index) += 1
                    End If
                Next
            End While
        End Using

        Return nf

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        ' Always specify a full path to a file that you use.
        Dim testFile = "C:\temp\randNums.txt"
        CreateTestFile(testFile)
        Dim nf = GetNumberFrequencies(testFile)

        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) In nf
            Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key & " - " & kvp.Value)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Sample output:

```
0 - 1013
1 - 963
2 - 991
3 - 1033
4 - 1001
5 - 966
6 - 962
7 - 1006
8 - 1018
9 - 1047
```

To use the GetNumberFrequencies function on a form, you could:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    Dim testFile = "C:\temp\randNums.txt"
    Dim nf = GetNumberFrequencies(testFile)
    Dim sb As New Text.Stringbuilder("Digit   Frequency" & VbNewLine)

    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) In nf
        sb.Append(kvp.Key & "      " & kvp.Value & VbNewLine)
    Next

    rtbshow.Text = sb.ToString()

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code but nothing happened, there was no error so do I have to do something to make the Console run ??

Comment: @ResshantanMorgan Did you create a new Console Application for it? I made it as a complete program that will run that way, then you can take any parts out of it that you want to. (I assume that you changed the "C:\temp" directory to something that already exists.)

Comment: I've had to solve this problem in interviews and exercises for a new job here or there, and I think a dictionary is generally what they're looking for too.

Comment: @Andrew Morton Yeah i did change the C:\temp cause I thought that was just your file path on your computer and I think I know what the problem I was running it on a form instead of a module but now that i put it into a module how do i run it? I read only that i have to make the module public and call it from a form but its not working

Comment: @ResshantanMorgan I updated my answer with an example of how you might use the GetNumberFrequencies function on a form.

Answer (score 0):

`File.ReadAllText` returns everything in the file as a string. Next we declare some variables to hold the number of occurrences of each digit. A `String` in .net is also an array of `Char`. We can take advantage of this by using a `For Each` loop to check each character in the file, one by one. First, with a method of the `Char` class, we check `IsDigit`. If `True` we pick which `Integer` variable to increment with a `Select Case`.

```
Zero += 1
```

is a shortcut way to write

Zero = Zero + 1

Finally, we write the string to display the results. The `$` in front of the `String` means it is an interpolated string. You can insert variable directly into the string surrounded by braces, `{ }`. This replaces `String.Format` or a dizzying number of quotes and ampersands. In recent versions of Visual Studio you can hit Enter to indicate a new line without having to enter any new line characters.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FileContents = File.ReadAllText("numbers.txt")
    Dim Zero, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine As Integer
    For Each c In FileContents
        If Char.IsDigit(c) Then
            Select Case c
                Case "0"c
                    Zero += 1
                Case "1"c
                    One += 1
                Case "2"c
                    Two += 1
                Case "3"c
                    Three += 1
                Case "4"c
                    Four += 1
                Case "5"c
                    Five += 1
                Case "6"c
                    Six += 1
                Case "7"c
                    Seven += 1
                Case "8"c
                    Eight += 1
                Case "9"c
                    Nine += 1
            End Select
        End If
    Next
    Dim DisplayResults = $"0    {Zero}
1    {One}
2    {Two}
3    {Three}
4    {Four}
5    {Five}
6    {Six}
7    {Seven}
8    {Eight}
9    {Nine}"
    MessageBox.Show(DisplayResults)
End Sub
```